# LinqtoSQL bring back only need

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In my data service I want to return just max dateTime and only query the database for that data I need. This  will help cutting down the data that the server is returning. But I am not sure about when I use the `Get()` and the model if that is returning the full data base on the model?

Model

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Templates")]
```

DataService

```
public DateTime? GetTemplateMaxModifiedDat()
{
    var result = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Template>().Get()
           .Where(t=>t.IsCurrentVersion && t.Status == (short)TemplateMode.Published)
           .OrderBy(t => t.TemplateIdMain)
           .ThenBy(t => t.TemplateIdNumeric)
           .ThenBy(t => t.TemplateIdAlt)
           .ToList()
           .Select(t => new
                  {
                      Modified = t.Modified
                  })
                  .Distinct().ToList();

        var q = result.OrderByDescending(T => T.Modified).FirstOrDefault();
        return q.Modified;
}
```

updated method

```
    public DateTime? GetTemplateMaxModifiedDate()
    {
        var result = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Template>()
            .Get(x => x.IsCurrentVersion && x.Status == (short)TemplateMode.Published)
            .Max(x => x.Modified);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, - don't use `.ToList()` - Secondly, what is the point of all the sorting and distinct etc when you can just use Max.

Comment: Why don’t I want to use the ‘tolist()’?

Comment: Because it is telling Linq2Sql that you **need** to get the results **into memory** at the point that you call it. In the case of the first call it is before your select and hence you are asking sql for every single column and every record what matches your where criteria. It will also spend time sorting the records into the order you specified. If you remove the first call, then the second will only select the modified column, but could  still return multiple entries. Without the ToLists method, you will be asking Sql to return you just one record and one column.

Comment: I updated the method to use Max and remove the toList